# Does Google Cloud Spanner support stored procedures?

Tags: database, stored-procedures, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Does Google Cloud Spanner support stored procedures?

I've had a quick search through the docs at https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/overview but couldn't find any reference to stored procs / user defined routines anywhere.

It would be good to find out for certain if they are/aren't supported.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it does not support stored procedures. You could use something like App Engine for small server side scripts or call Dataflow jobs for larger ones.